# QGIS GPS bluetooth connection

Tags: qgis, python, gps, windows-8

I have setup a Haicom bluetooth gps on a machine running Windows8 and have used GPSGate to create some virtual COM ports. I have valid data arriving at the COM port, but then I run QGIS and try to connect to the specified COM port and each time QGIS crashes. Can anyone suggest what is going on please?

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS forum.Please let us know which qgis version you are using?If you installed 3rd party plugins then it crashing some times.Try to assign different GPS port then try or disable 3rd party plugin then try..hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi, I am using the latest 1.8.0 and have been doing further investigations into my problem. It appears that it was because of the syntax of the info that I entered...if you don't type COM1 correctly...COM1: COM 1 etc. A little trick to be careful of! Many thanks, Bruce